# npm 5 build cache and transfer to offline machine

Tags: npm

In npm 5, is it possible to build out the cache on a machine with internet connectivity, then transfer the cache to a machine that never touches the internet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to make this work. If anyone else has a better solution, I would very much like to hear it!

1. I cleared out my `%appdata%/npm` and `%appdata%/npm-cache` folders
2. Globally installed all of the modules that I wanted to transfer to the offline machine.
3. To validate that the cache was complete, I would run `npm install --offline` after globally installing the packages.
4. If any dependency packages were missing during the install, I would globally install the dependency, then rerun `npm install --offline` until all of the dependencies successfully installed.
5. I transferred both the `%appdata%/npm` and `%appdata%/npm-cache` folders to the same location for my user profile on the offline machine.

When I ran `npm install --offline` on the offline machine for my ASP.NET Core / Angular project, all of the dependencies successfully installed from the newly transferred cache.

Comment: Does this work without globally installing the packages?

Comment: In the latest version of NPM, all dependencies that you explicitly install are cached (whether installed globally, or at the project level). What I do to capture all package dependencies as well is create a dummy NPM project, install all of the packages I want to move over, run `npm cache verify`, then transfer the `npm` and `npm-cache` directories specified above.

Comment: Also, you no longer have to specify `--offline` in the latest versions of NPM. I'm currently using v. 5.6.0

Comment: Looks like the package-lock.json is all important here.  In npm v4.X, I would just update the package.json on the offline computer and be fine.  In npm v5.X I kept receiving an ENOTCACHED error.  When I copied the package-lock.json file to my offline project, then modules were correctly received.