# Installation of React JS on Offline PC

Tags: reactjs

I am unable to use npm install -g create-react-app as my computer is disconnected from the internet for development purpose. May I know where how to install "react-app" on offline PCs?

Comment: Probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45508832/npm-5-build-cache-and-transfer-to-offline-machine

Answer (score 0):

Installing CRA (Create React App) requires an internet connection. You can get around this by using a different computer and transferring the source code and build it from scratch.

1. Using a different computer (one with an internet connection) navigate to the create-react-app GitHub repository: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app and download the .zip
2. Open the .zip on your offline computer (use a USB)
3. build from source (see README and DOCS)